# Dollar Value of a Trade (finance)

Tags: finance

When you trade stocks on the market, what best describes the product of shares × price?

My candidates are *Capital, Amount, Value,* ...?

Comment: You use the word *value* yourself, and the phrase *high-value transaction* features in relevant Google results, so that seems a good candidate. Google isn't an entirely acceptable source for corroboration, though, so this is merely a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most investment sites (ShareBuilder and Morningstar, to name two) refer to the product of the Quantity of Shares (or Shares Held) times the Current Price (or Quote) as the *[Market Value](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/m/marketvalue.asp)*.

Here's condensed example from ShareBuilder:

```
Symbol Quote   Quantity Market Value
AAPL   $438.91 10.0956  $4,431.06
```